# Kubernetes: Merge files from a volume into a target directory, without using subPath

Tags: kubernetes, configmap

Using `subPath`, I can mount individual files from a volume into a container directory while still retaining the other files already present in the directory.

However, `subPath` requires creating an entry in the manifest for each file to be mounted.
I want to mount all files in a volume without naming each file explicitly in the manifest.

As far as possible I do not want to use init containers.

Is this possible in Kubernetes?

Comment: This is not possible in kubernetes (because this isn't possible using the bind mount facility of the Linux kernel).

Comment: Are there any Kustomize "tricks" to perhaps patch the deployment manifest to mount individual files from a volume?

Comment: I would mount the volume in a different location and then use an initContainer to copy files into the target directory. There aren't any tricks you can do with kustomize; I think the only real alternative is to just create a bunch of subPath volumeMounts (or use some sort of templating tool to generate your manifest so that you can automate the creation of those subPath entries).